# how to sent 2 parameter value in load jquery

Tags: php, jquery

```
 var siteid = $("#OperationSiteId option:selected").val();
 $("#OperationSiteequipmentId").load("<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'Operations', 'action'=>'equipment_dropdown')) ?>/"+$(equipment).val()+"/"+$(siteid).val()
```

Please correct me what i have done wrong , i could not get siteid value.

for example :
equipment value is 5 
and site id value is 175

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#OperationSiteequipmentId").load( url [, callBackFunc ]);
```

The syntax for load is a URL, and optional callback function. If you want to pass 2 parameter in URL it is perfectly fine. Still it will be the part of the URL.

```
e.g http://example.com?equipment=5&siteId=175
```

You've to generate this as a single URL and pass it. Rest all will work fine. Please try like this. This should work fine

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to get the siteid value again on the load. Since you have retrieved the siteid to **var siteid**. you can use the same value.

```
 var siteid = $("#OperationSiteId option:selected").val();
 $("#OperationSiteequipmentId").load("<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'Operations', 'action'=>'equipment_dropdown')) ?>/"+$(equipment).val()+"/"+siteid);
```

Comment: Thank you got it . i understand now how it work.. sory i just start learning programing languange